# git a file with another name

Tags: php, git

Suppose when I run commands on my computer, I define environment as:

```
define('HOST', 'localhost');
```

but when I commit on server instead of that, I want another code appears:

```
define('HOST', 'server');
```

so I make two files index.php and index2.php(which is supposed to be created by script dynamically)

how to commit index2.php in behalf of index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution to this is to keep environmental variables in a file that is not tracked by git and include it in to the php file.

eg:

index.php

```
require_once('parameters.php');
// rest of your code
```

parameters.php (for local environment)

```
define('HOST', 'localhost');
// other parameters that you might want to define for localhost
```

.gitignore

```
./parameters.php
```

As you can see parameters file now contains your local configs and is not tracked by git. You can create another parameters.php file on your remote server with configurations for that environment.

parameters.php (for remote environment)

```
define('HOST', 'server');
// other parameters that you might want to define for localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an issue because some files depend on your configuration, and you don't have the same config on your computer and on your server.

A solution could be to put in Git a file with a generic configuration, and to let it be overridden.

That's what [Dokuwiki](http://dokuwiki.org) does: in their repo there's a [local.php.dist](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/master/conf/local.php.dist), but users can provide a local.php to override it. This local.php isn't meant to go in Git ([and is in fact gitignored](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/0913e605b95bb93d7e194d237015ebb0c92b3030/.gitignore#L3))

Answer (score 0):

I am typically resorting to *environment variables* set in the (web) server. For example, in the Apache configuration or .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT production
```

In your app you can then have different configurations for different environments; I keep mine in the form of a YAML file:

```
default:
    foo: bar
    baz: 42
production:
    foo: blarg
    baz: 84
```

You then look for the environment variable:

```
$env = getenv('MYAPP_ENVIRONMENT');
```

And decide based on that which configuration to use.

For sensitive values like database passwords, which should not be stored in the repository, I'm even allowing to set arbitrary values via environment variables which are merged into the config files. E.g.:

```
SetEnv MYAPP_FOO blörg
```

(The above would overwrite `foo` in any configuration.)